# How to run BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator using user application-default refresh token with DataflowRunner

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

Is it possible to run Apache Airflow DAG that submits Beam pipeline using DataflowRunner via `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` task

WITHOUT specifying as operator parameter

- `--service_account_name`

WITHOUT having any explicit environment variable set

- `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`
- `GCP_PROJECT`

WITH using only:

- `gcloud auth application-default login`
- `gcloud config set project`

for GCP auth.

My intent is to NOT use any service account keys (for local development with [airflow](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/composer-local-dev#configure-credentials) and dataflow) but instead, private user credentials refresh token.

With this setup, I manage to proceed in airflow google hook condition  [hooks/base_google.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py#L541-L551) but then Apache Beam Job submit to Dataflow Runner [dataflow_runner.py, apitools/credentials_lib.py](https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/master/apitools/base/py/credentials_lib.py#L133-L157) fails to identify my refresh token that is set using `gcloud auth application-default login`.

```
[2023-05-12, 09:41:17 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:312} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2023-05-12, 09:41:17 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:109} WARNING - /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:70 UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK without a quota project. You might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. We recommend you rerun `gcloud auth application-default login` and make sure a quota project is added. Or you can use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
[2023-05-12, 09:42:40 UTC] {beam.py:131} INFO - Start waiting for Apache Beam process to complete.
[2023-05-12, 09:42:46 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py:2138: BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to <pipeline>.options will not be supported
[2023-05-12, 09:42:46 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   is_streaming_pipeline = p.options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming
[2023-05-12, 09:42:46 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_file_loads.py:1128: BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to <pipeline>.options will not be supported
[2023-05-12, 09:42:46 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   temp_location = p.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location
[2023-05-12, 09:42:52 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Executing command: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', 'setup.py', 'sdist', '--dist-dir', '/tmp/tmp8xeer0dc']
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt, README.md
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - 
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - warning: check: missing required meta-data: url
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - 
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - warning: check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) should be supplied
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - 
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Downloading source distribution of the SDK from PyPi
[2023-05-12, 09:43:00 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Executing command: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmp8xeer0dc', 'apache-beam==2.37.0', '--no-deps', '--no-binary', ':all:']
[2023-05-12, 09:43:15 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Staging SDK sources from PyPI: dataflow_python_sdk.tar
[2023-05-12, 09:43:15 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Downloading binary distribution of the SDK from PyPi
[2023-05-12, 09:43:15 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Executing command: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmp8xeer0dc', 'apache-beam==2.37.0', '--no-deps', '--only-binary', ':all:', '--python-version', '38', '--implementation', 'cp', '--abi', 'cp38', '--platform', 'manylinux1_x86_64']
[2023-05-12, 09:43:23 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Staging binary distribution of the SDK from PyPI: apache_beam-2.37.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
[2023-05-12, 09:43:23 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
[2023-05-12, 09:43:23 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:root:Default Python SDK image for environment is apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.37.0
[2023-05-12, 09:43:23 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:root:Using provided Python SDK container image: gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python38:2.37.0
[2023-05-12, 09:43:23 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:root:Python SDK container image set to "gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python38:2.37.0" for Docker environment
[2023-05-12, 09:43:25 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner.translations:==================== <function pack_combiners at 0x402ef86a60> ====================
[2023-05-12, 09:43:25 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.fn_api_runner.translations:==================== <function sort_stages at 0x402ef87280> ====================
[2023-05-12, 09:43:27 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:Setting socket default timeout to 60 seconds.
[2023-05-12, 09:43:27 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:socket default timeout is 60.0 seconds.
[2023-05-12, 09:43:30 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:oauth2client.client:Timeout attempting to reach GCE metadata service.
[2023-05-12, 09:43:30 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - WARNING:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:Unable to find default credentials to use: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
[2023-05-12, 09:43:30 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - Connecting anonymously.
[2023-05-12, 09:43:46 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - INFO:oauth2client.contrib.multiprocess_file_storage:Credential file /home/airflow/.apitools.token created
[2023-05-12, 09:43:46 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - WARNING:oauth2client.contrib.multiprocess_file_storage:Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
[2023-05-12, 09:43:46 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - WARNING:oauth2client.contrib.multiprocess_file_storage:Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/youtube/beam/my_job.py", line 179, in <module>
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     run()
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/youtube/beam/my_job.py", line 174, in run
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     pipeline.run()
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 546, in run
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     return Pipeline.from_runner_api(
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 573, in run
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 574, in run_pipeline
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     self.dataflow_client = apiclient.DataflowApplicationClient(
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 555, in __init__
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     self._client = dataflow.DataflowV1b3(
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/clients/dataflow/dataflow_v1b3_client.py", line 50, in __init__
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     super().__init__(
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 261, in __init__
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     self._SetCredentials(**credentials_args)
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 312, in _SetCredentials
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     self._credentials = credentials_lib.GetCredentials(**args)
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apitools/base/py/credentials_lib.py", line 157, in GetCredentials
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING -     raise exceptions.CredentialsError('Could not create valid credentials')
[2023-05-12, 10:03:47 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - apitools.base.py.exceptions.CredentialsError: Could not create valid credentials
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - Generating new OAuth credentials ...
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - 
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - Your browser has been opened to visit:
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - 
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO -     https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=1042881264118.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8090%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&access_type=offline&response_type=code
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - 
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - application with the command-line parameter
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - 
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO -   --noauth_local_webserver
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - 
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - Failed to find "code" in the query parameters of the redirect.
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - Invalid authorization: Try running with --noauth_local_webserver.
... now starts repeating ...
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {beam.py:150} INFO - Process exited with return code: 1
[2023-05-12, 10:03:48 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1702} ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

I checked docs and do not understand why [User credentials provided by using the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#personal) does not work in Dataflow when submitted by Airflow?

Running without Airflow, Standalone Dataflow manually works:

```
INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:Setting socket default timeout to 60 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:socket default timeout is 60.0 seconds.
DEBUG:google.auth._default:Checking None for explicit credentials as part of auth process...
DEBUG:google.auth._default:Checking Cloud SDK credentials as part of auth process...
.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:78: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK without a quota project. You might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. See the following page for troubleshooting: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds.
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
DEBUG:root:Connecting using Google Application Default Credentials.
... beam continues and dataflow submit works ...
```

Comment: I would recommend to contact Google support for this as they have better visibility of your project's log and resource usage for investigation.  https://cloud.google.com/contact